# Can't send mail using SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I want to send mail using SmtpClient class, but it not work.
Code:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(obMailSetting.UserName, obMailSetting.Password);

smtpClient.Host = obMailSetting.HostMail;
smtpClient.Port = obMailSetting.Port;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.EnableSsl = obMailSetting.Connect_Security;//true
//smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;//It would work if i uncomment this line
smtpClient.Send(email);
```

It throws an exception:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

I'm sure that username and password is correct. Is there any problem in my code?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you try to include domain in third parameter of NetworkCredential ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.Subject = "Your Subject";
 mail.From = new MailAddress("senderMailAddress");
 mail.To.Add("ReceiverMailAddress");
 mail.Body = "Hello! your mail content goes here...";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
 smtp.EnableSsl = true;
 NetworkCredential netCre = 
                  new NetworkCredential("SenderMailAddress","SenderPassword" );
 smtp.Credentials = netCre;

 try
  {
     smtp.Send(mail);                
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {   
    // Handle exception here 
  }
```

You can try [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41fbab2b-6779-471d-b183-dcaaea13a14a/smtp-error-the-server-response-was-571-client-was-not-authenticated-?forum=tfsgeneral) out :
In the Exchange Management Console, under the Server Configuration node, select Hub Transport and the name of the server.  In the Receive Connectors pane, open either of the Recive Connectors (my default installation created 2) or you can create a new one just for TFS (I also tried this and it worked).  For any of these connectors, open Properties and on the Permission Groups tab ensure that Anonymous Users is selected (it's not by default).

Or
You can also try [this](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.2.aspx) by initializing `SmtpClient` as follows:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: Basically same code as in the question so how does that answer the question how to solve that _5.7.1 Client was not authenticated_ is returned by the server?

Comment: Yes, It's almost the same as mime.
@Arshad: Hi friend, so which might cause this exception?

Answer (score 1):

The server responds with *5.7.1 Client was not authenticated* but only if you do not set `UseDefaultCredentials` to `true`. This indicates that the `NetworkCredential` that you are using is in fact wrong.

Either the user name or password is wrong or perhaps you need to specify a domain? You can use another constructor to specify the domain:

```
new NetworkCredential("MyUserName", "MyPassword", "MyDomain");
```

Or perhaps the user that you specify does not have the necessary rights to send mail on the SMTP server but then I would expect another server response.

Comment: I have similar issue some one can help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25543233/unable-to-send-the-mailmessage-in-asp-net