# Can't send email using SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient, dmz

I'm trying to send an email via .net smtp. I am receiving this message:
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("server", 587);
SmtpServer.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new   System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

mail.From = new MailAddress(FromMail);
mail.To.Add("emailaddress");
mail.Bcc.Add("emailaddress");
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.Body = body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

The issue I believe is that the servers are located in the DMZ...anyone have any insight on how to fix this? If we assign the user with domain admin rights, the emails work...due to security reasons we don't want to go that route.

Comment: `EnableSsl = true` - the error states you need a secure connection yes?

Comment: not necessarily, if I keep that to false and give my network credentials 'domain admin' rights, the emails go through OK

Comment: might be a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20092414/cant-send-mail-using-smtpclient  Also, it sounds like less of a code issue and more of a permissions issue on the smtp server then @scruse24

Comment: `"If we assign the user with domain admin rights, the emails work"` indicates this is a permissions error. You need to check the user account settings you are trying to send the email with. I'm not sure there's anything we can do for you since we don't (and can't) know how your SMTP or domain users and permissions settings are set up.

Comment: @user1666620 we also cannot send anonymous emails either(even though the box is checked)...would that be related as well?

Comment: @scruse24 I don't know - what error do you get? Since you are trying to connect to a server on a DMZ, I imagine you still need to provide credentials to get access to the SMTP. I think anonymous access only allows a user to send an email purporting to come from a different email address. You still need permissions to send the email.

Comment: issue resolved...see answer below. Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved...the network team didn't have port 587 available...once they added it, emails started working for anonymous sender. I no longer need to use credentials. Thanks to all who replied.